# SignalR clients not aware of connection failure

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm having some trouble with SignalR.. Everything seems to be working fine server-side. The problem is when my javascript clients lose internet connection for some time: when they reconnect to the internet they never try to establish a new connection to SignalR server.

I think this is happening because they are never aware that they lost internet connection in the first place. When I check for $.signalR.connectionState it gives me a value of 1, as if they were connected.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Some code to show that reproduces the error ?

Comment: Try setting `$.connection.hub.logging` to `true`: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#logging Then report back with the log output.

Answer (score 0):

In this [sample](https://github.com/gustavo-armenta/CookieAuthenticationSample/blob/master/SelfHost/Scripts/AuthorizeEchoHub.js), javascript client first subscribes to all events (error, stateChanged, etc) before starting the connection. Also, check javascript console in your browser to have a better idea of what SignalR is doing.